# Large links preview in facebook walls

Tags: facebook

Please have a look at the following images:

[image: large link]
[image: small link]

As you can see these two links both send to an external website but, the big link misleads the user into thinking that it is a picture, therefore boosting clicks, likens and shares on the item.

On the other hand the second picture is generated using the traditional sharer.php feature. Does anyone know how to get a large image for link previews? Or is it something achievable only via paid advertising? (I am not sure about this one, that big link is just a blog post, no reason for paid ads)

Comment: This has been discussed here a couple of times already: Facebook is “experimenting”, as they say, with the new larger format to see how users react to it – but they chose where and when to use it. All you can do to increase your chances of getting the bigger display is providing og:images that are large enough, the recent recommendations are here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/maximizing-distribution-media-content/#images

Comment: does og:images have to go in the header? That means no single page apps? Or am I getting this completely wrong? How does one set og:image in a page where there more than one image?

Comment: Yes, it goes in the `<head>`, and yes, the OG information is bound to a specific URL, because the URL is what FB uses to identify Open Graph objects. If you want more than one image for the user to chose from when sharing, then use multiple og:image tags. Please the OG docs for basics, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/using-objects/ and http://ogp.me/